# The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/yii2/yii2-app-basic/web/assets

Tags: linux, yii, yii2, centos, permissions

Во время установки yii2 получил вот такую ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Многие советуют узнать имя пользователя apache и дать ему привелегии на директорию *./assets*, выполнив данную команду, 
**ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep**

[image: консоль выводит это]

Comment: нужны права на эту директорию. chmod 777

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Comment: SElinux блочит, решение смотри [тут](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50641)

Если быстро проверить, то пропиши `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /ПУТЬ/ИМЯ_ПАПКИ`

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень простым, достаточно было нажать на кнопку **'Details'** в браузере ошибок SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно столкнулся с этой проблемой на сервере с **CentOS**.

Решение проблемы написали в комментария к вопросу, но я хочу оформить его в виде ответа:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/folder
```

Как сказал @k-lobastov: "*Блокирует **SELinux***", даже если права (CHMOD) стоят 777.